# Sorting multiple value lookup column - alternatives

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, modern-experience

Is it possible to sort lookup columns that allow multiple values or is there any alternative that can be applied in a modern list view?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is any OOB solution to sort lookup column in modern list view.

You need to consider custom solutions with SPFx extension.

Reference:

[Migrating from JSLink to SharePoint Framework Extensions.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions)

Answer (score -1):

In SP 2010 & 2013 it's not possible to sort by multi-value lookup columns, I don't know about Sharepoint Online.  But presumably it's not possible.

[image: Multi-value look-up columns]

[image: not possible to sort]

### Other Notes

In your lookup column, if you go to Edit Column there is a section titled `Add a column to show each of these additional fields:` - you can select additional columns to bring to your destination list.  It might be worth experimenting with these to see if an 'additional column' can be filtered.